# SwiftUI How to access @AppStorage variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, appstorage

I'm really new to Swift and iOS apps and couldn't figure the following out.

I'm trying to create a simple 5 steps rating element storing a value to the user defaults. It works however not "on the fly" meaning the user can't see the change instantly but only on relaunching the app. The rating indicated through different opacities.

**So, the problem is:**
The changes are not shown instantly on tapping but only after relaunching the app.

I read articles about @AppStorage but couldn't figure it out.

```
struct EverythingView: View {
   @AppStorage("customRating") var customTemp: Int = 1

   HStack (spacing: 6) {
      ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { index in
         Circle()
            .fill(Color(.green))
            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
            .onTapGesture {
               customRating = index
               print(customRating) // prints the correct value on the fly
             }
             .opacity(index > customRating ? 0.5 : 1) // does not update the opacity of the circles on the fly, only on relaunching the app
      }
   }
}
```

Do I have to access @AppStorage again somewhere inside the loop? From what I understood it updates and propagates itself automatically?

Thanks for any tips!

**EDIT:**
Using an `@State` instead of `@AppStorage` `var` works as expected.

Comment: customRating or customTemp? And how is it visible to the user?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for pointing it out, I changed it, however it seems that it wasn't the issue   
The `customRating` variable is not visible to the user itself, only the `Circles()` indicating the rating is. The variable is stored in the user settings.

Comment: I ran it using @user3680644 corrected code, and could not reproduce the problem, the opacities are changing when tapped. What version of Simulator and Xcode are you using, I'm using the latest.

Comment: @user3680644 code works well for me as well. What does 
`The customRating variable is not visible to the user itself, only the Circles() indicating the rating is.`
 mean?

Answer (score 1):

you're doing it right you just have a typo in your first line. your @AppStorage property also needs to be named customRating

```
struct EverythingView: View {
   @AppStorage("customRating") var customRating: Int = 1 //<---property name should be customRating

    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
        HStack (spacing: 6) {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { index in
             Circle()
                .fill(Color(.green))
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                .onTapGesture {
                   customRating = index
                   print(customRating) // prints the correct value on the fly
                 }
                 .opacity(index > customRating ? 0.5 : 1) // does not update the opacity of the circles on the fly, only on relaunching the app
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I corrected it, however it seems that it wasn't the issue  Thanks anyways for pointing it out though!